# Should I use autoremove in these packages?

Tags: package-management

When I run `sudo apt-get autoremove` it is trying to remove the followings packages:

```
linux-headers-3.16.0-40 
linux-headers-3.16.0-40-generic 
linux-image-3.16.0-40-generic
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-40-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.16.0-40-generic
```

Should I really remove them? They look important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in Terminal:

```
uname -r
```

*Only if the output **is not***:

```
3.16.0-40-generic
```

... you can remove the packages.

Afterwards, reboot the machine and try again, maybe you have upgraded your kernel without rebooting after upgrading.

Comment: Reboot the machine and try it again, maybe you have upgraded your kernel without a reboot after the upgrade.